# How to number(and refer) a set of equations in an align environment correctly?

Tags: align, numbering, labels, typography

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \diff{S}{t} &= \Lambda  -\beta(1-\rho)(1-\xi)SI  -(\mu+\rho+\xi)S,\\[1ex]\nonumber
    \diff{I}{t} &=\beta(1-\rho)(1-\xi)SI-(\mu+\alpha+\theta+\gamma )I, \\[1ex] \label{1}
    \diff{R}{t} &=(\theta+\gamma)I+(\rho+\xi)S-\mu R,\nonumber
    \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

How would I put the number in "middle" of these equations? here is is nice as there's 3 equations but what if there was 2,4 or 5 equations?

***EDIT***: Using Egreg's Comment on the following set of equations:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    d S&=\left[\Lambda(r(t))-\beta(r(t))(1-\rho(r(t)))(1-\xi(r(t)))SI-(\mu(r(t))+\rho(r(t))+\xi(r(t)))S \right] d t\\
    &+\sigma_1(r(t))S d B_1+\int_M D_1(r(t),y) S(t-) \tilde{N}(dt,dy),\\
    d I&=\left[\beta(r(t))(1-\rho(r(t)))(1-\xi(r(t)))SI-(\mu(r(t))+\alpha(r(t))+\theta(r(t))+\gamma(r(t)))I \right]d t\\
    &+\sigma_2(r(t)) I d B_2+\int_M D_2(r(t),y) I(t-) \tilde{N}(dt,dy),\\
    d R&=\left[(\theta(r(t))+\gamma(r(t)))I+(\rho(r(t))+\xi(r(t)))S-\mu(r(t))R \right]d t+\sigma_3(r(t)) R d B_3\\
    &+ \int_M D_3(r(t),y) R(t-) \tilde{N}(dt,dy).
    \end{aligned} \label{7.2}
    \end{equation}
\end{equation}
```

produces one number but it is not centralised, how can we fix this?

Comment: Single number for the block? `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}<same input>\end{aligned}\end{equation}` But remove `\nonumber` and place `\label` outside `aligned`.

Comment: @egreg Yes. I will try this.

Comment: Please check your examples before posting. `! LaTeX Error: Environment align undefined.`

Comment: @egreg Thank you, this will help me invaluably.. although major surgery is required in the thesis now...

Comment: @egreg Please check the edit, how can we align this?

Comment: @Math The equations are too wide.

Comment: @egreg so is this the optimal solution? or is there a better one?

Comment: @Math Definitely suboptimal, because there's a 52pt overfull, which is huge. It's your job to split the equations so they fit.

Comment: @egreg Can you propose any fixes?